# CoreData issue: -[NSManagedObject setValue:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have Created the entity(`Article`) and able to fetch saved data. Now I want to show the data on view controller but on the third line, it is getting a crash("`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Article modiffied_date]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800009ccf0`").

`currentSelectedArticle` is object of `Article`

```
 1. title = currentSelectedArticle?.title 
 2. image_url = currentSelectedArticle?.image_url 
 3. newdate = currentSelectedArticle?.modiffied_date
```

But When I used to print `currentSelectedArticle`.It's showing below result.

```
 <Article: 0x60800009ccf0> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000080024 <x-coredata://D5402915-E542-4044-B14B-A3BF423847EC/Article/p2> ; data: <fault>)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure `modiffied_date` matches an actual property on the `Article` object. Looks like you have a typo in the word "modified" at the very least.

Comment: modiffied_date is actual property of Article. I think the issue with the currentSelectedArticle entity which is null to print(entity: <null>).

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The error says "unrecognized selector" and the printout shows that it's an `Article` object, so all evidence points to it being a problem with the property you are trying to access. I don't think the "entity : <null>" thing means what you think it means. The Article object itself is not null. Did you add the property to the CoreData map?

Comment: Plz, check the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709606/passing-coredata-object-between-controllers-in-swift.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while pulling data from CoreData ! So , I implemented it in Swift 3 like this ..

Step 1 : Add `import CoreData`

Step 2 : Add the code below . .

```
let context = ( UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate ).persistentContainer.viewContext
var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
request = Article.fetchRequest()
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
let arrayArticle = try context.fetch(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you print the description of a managed object before it's been faulted in, you don't get a lot of info. I suggest you try the following code to debug:

```
if let article = currentSelectedArticle {
    title = article.title
    image_url = article.image_url
    print("Selected article: \(article)")
}
```

It seems like `title` and `image_url` are valid, so retrieving them will cause Core Data to fault in the object, then when you `print` you'll be able to see the values for all of its properties.