# FPassing Coredata object Between Controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am passing Article object from ViewcontrollerA to ViewcontrollerB. But Output is different. I am not able to figure out why the entity is null in ViewcontrollerB.

I used to below code to print the Article object in both controllers.

```
  print(String(describing:listOfArticles))
```

> Output

ViewcontrollerA.

```
  <Article: 0x600000281810> (entity: Article; id: 0xd00000000168001c <x-coredata://949275DD-E091-49E8-A0D0-2C362B616F97/Article/p90> ; data: <fault>)
```

ViewcontrollerB.

```
Optional(<Article: 0x600000283610> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd0000000000c0012 <x-coredata://949275DD-E091-49E8-A0D0-2C362B616F97/Article/p3> ; data: <fault>))
```

In ViewcontrollerB `entity: <null>;` is null always. It is getting crashed when I try to use the object.

Push ViewcontollerA code:-

```
guard let viewArticelArray = topStories_presenter.fetchAllAritcleForTopStories(fetchedResultsController:fetchedResultsController) else {
    return
}
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsCollectionViewController") as! NewsCollectionViewController
vc.listArticle = viewArticelArray[0]
parentNavigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

ViewcontollerB

```
 var listArticle :Article!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print(String(describing:listArticle))       
        }
```

FetchResultViewController code :

```
 fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<TopStorie> = {
        // Create Fetch Request
        let moc = CoreDataHelper().managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TopStorie> = TopStorie.fetchRequest()
        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"typeid", ascending: true)]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category contains[c]%@", self.title!)
        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:moc, sectionNameKeyPath:"typeid", cacheName: nil)
        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

Comment: Please show the code for passing the data from one VC to the other.

Comment: Add code passing the data from one VC

Comment: Can you print out viewArticleArray[0] from your PushViewController code?

Comment: Check ViewcontrollerA output. I have print viewArticleArray[0] .

Comment: Show where you print it in ViewcontrollerB

Comment: I have added code for ViewcontrollerB

Comment: Can you post what you are using to setup the fetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: Put your `print` statement in `viewDidAppear`.